# Getting ckeditor's stylesheet parser to work

Tags: css, ckeditor

I'm new to ckeditor and currently trying to customize it for implementation in my site. I managed to create and apply a custom config file with a customized toolbar, but don't seem to get to customize the styles in the built-in dropdown menu, following the instructions from the online documentation. I'd like to use a css file through the stylesheetparser plugin.

Here's the code I'm using in the config file:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
...
    config.stylesSet = [];
    config.extraPlugins = 'stylesheetparser';
    config.contentsCss = '/ckedit_custom/myStyles.css';
};
```

The stylesheet is located in the ckedit_custom folder which is in the site's root directory.

Result (so far) is an empty list in the styles dropdown list.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently has the status "confirmed bug" - 
http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8660